# undefined method will_save_change_to_email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I started an application with Rails 5.1.4 ; Devise 4.2 ; Mongoid 6.1.0.

When I trying to create an account, I got this error

> NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create undefined
>   method `will_save_change_to_email?' for #

I see some post on GitHub but I don't know how to fix that.
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4531#issuecomment-313600769

What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

This answer from MonFresh did it for me

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4531#issuecomment-323236400

> I just remembered we had to override email_changed? and email_was in our app because it's not a database field, so to be able to upgrade to Rails 5.1, all I had to do was rename email_changed? to will_save_change_to_email? and email_was to email_in_database.
>
> Unfortunately, these new Rails 5.1 methods are not yet documented here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html, but you can read about them here:
> rails/rails#25337 (comment)

I basically added the following alias to my Mongoid model (but I believe this has to do with ActiveModel)

```
alias will_save_change_to_email? email_changed?
```

Comment: This is the right answer, place alias will_save_change_to_email? email_changed? after your devise :database_authenticable, etc .... or before closing the class at the very end

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t want to use email as a default field for sign in, you can specify another. We will use `:username` as the field name in these examples, but you can use any field.

To implement this, uncomment the following text in `config/initializers/devise.rb` file and specify the field you want to use during sign in, such as `:username`:

```
config.authentication_keys = [:username]
```

Another way is to change your model:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :authentication_keys => [:username]
```

Then,add validations to your model:

`validates :email,uniqueness:  true`
    `validates :username,uniqueness:  true`

Then,create a migration and migrate:

`rails generate migration add_username_to_users username:string:uniq`
    `rake db:migrate`

Next, make sure you can set that field when you create and edit users. When using the [strong parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) feature in newer versions of Rails, permit reading of that parameter in the controller with `.permit(:username)`. Or if you’re using an older version of Rails, make the field accessible in your model with `attr_accessible :username` instead.

After this you can generate Devise views using the following command:

```
rails generate devise:views
```

And then you’ll need to modify the views in `app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb` and `app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb` to use the new form field.

Finally, you might need to change the error message that gets shown to the users if they provide incorrect credentials or when they are not found. You do this in `config/locales/devise.en.yml`. Look for the following:

```
invalid: 'Invalid email or password.'
not_found_in_database: 'Invalid email or password.'
```

and change it to this:

```
invalid: 'Invalid username or password.'
not_found_in_database: 'Invalid username or password.'
```

If you see

```
invalid: "Invalid %{authentication_keys} or password."
not_found_in_database: "Invalid %{authentication_keys} or password."
```

instead, you don’t need to change anything.

Note that if you aren’t using e-mail as your authentication key, then it may be the case that users can have multiple accounts with the same e-mail address. This will cause the “recoverable” module not to work well, as it will only include a link in the password reset e-mail to the first account for which it finds a matching e-mail. Here is [a thread on the Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/plataformatec-devise/Fr2TgDQcYmA) about how to implement adding all the accounts information into the password reset email.

**Important note**: If you use `validatable` module, define `email_required?` and `email_changed?`:

```
# app/models/model.rb
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :trackable, :lockable, :validatable

  def email_required?
    false
  end

  def email_changed?
    false
  end

  # use this instead of email_changed? for rails >= 5.1
  def will_save_change_to_email?
    false
  end

end
```

If you are using `confirmable` or `recoverable` module, you just need to define `email_changed?` to `false`.

Comment: The OP did specify that he was using Mongoid and it actually has to do with the mongoid gem I believe.